# NHibernate: Support for Char Columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracle10g, char

I am using NHibernate against a legacy database which uses Char column types (fixed Strings). I am mapping the char columns to strings in properties. Currently my criteria queries are failing if the value against which i am querying is not padded with spaces such that the length of the string is equal to the char column length. I dont want to manually pad in this way for all values. I was kind of looking that NHibernate will take care of this for me.

I tried the mapping with the following options:

```
<property name="Account">
  <column name="Account" sql-type="char(9)" length="9"/>
</property>
```

and

```
<property name="Account" type="AnsiChar">
  <column name="Account"/>
</property>
```

The first has no affect and the problem with the second mapping is that it assumes that the property type should be of type System.Char and not string. 
I am looking for a mapping where i can map Oracle's Char data type to normal string.

Comment: Is the `NHibernate.Dialect` set properly?

Comment: yes, it is set to NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a UserType to trim the strings.

Comment: For me it is not the padded strings returned from database which is a cause of concern, it is more that my criteria query parameter values  have to be padded with appropriate length while doing a select on an object.

Comment: If I recall correctly, that was part of my UserType implementation.  I had to override equals to compare trimmed strings.  You shouldn't have to pad a string before you send it to the DB in a WHERE clause -- it should automatically pad it for you.